# Is there a way in android to write common border xml with different background color?

Tags: android

In Android I know how to have a rounded border with some background color.

But For making rounded border in different elements I have to write almost same xml again and again with just different colors.

Is there a way I could write a xml which only gives rounded border but does get background color dynamically?

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-change-the-layout-theme-of-an-android-application/25837 go through above link

Comment: Do you want me to give different theme for different elements?

Comment: definately. You need to create differenr themes and you can apply that themes dynamically

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems a good way.

Comment: Can I apply theme to a particular element rather than an activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101283/discussion-between-govan-and-user3676184).

Comment: yes. But you need to set first that theme to activity. And after that you can appy for particular element